# Create a Record from an object of arrays variable in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object, partials

I have a variable that is an object of arrays:

```js
cssColorsObject = {
    red: ["lightsalmon", "salmon", "darksalmon", "lightcoral", "indianred", "crimson", "firebrick", "red", "darkred"],
    orange: ["coral", "tomato", "orangered", "gold", "orange", "darkorange"],
    yellow: [...
}
```

I would like to create a type/interface for future object variables that contain some of the keys (eg "red", "orange", "yellow"), and some or all of that key color's properties, eg:

```js
{
    red: ["lightsalmon", "salmon"], // OK
    orange: [], //OK
    yellow: ["lightsalmon"], // NOT OK - because light salmon is a color associated with the "red" key in the original object
}
```

I have worked out the following:

```js
type CssColorKeys = keyof typeof cssColorsObject; // = "red" | "orange" | "yellow" | "green" , etc
type CssColorValues = typeof cssColorsObject[CssColorKeys][number]; // = "lightsalmon" | "salmon"... | "maroon"
type NewRecord = Record<CssColorKeys, CssColorValues> // Not what I want as this requires all properties and the exact same array.
```

I imagine I need to use partials, but I'm struggling to implement them here.

---

Full credit to @captain-yossarian for answer below. I just wanted to add a simplified solution, based on his answer:

```js
type CssColorsPartial = Partial<{
    [Prop in keyof typeof cssColorsObject]: Array<typeof cssColorsObject[Prop][number]>;
}>;
```

I've created another `type` for a mapped type with mandatory keys and optional array values [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wa1BhCAbaVAeQCMArYBeAXjgG8BYAKDlbimABMAuOAbQBEeAJYBzABYxUAQzwBbFAIA0cATPmKVAztKgBrdQuTLVIiTCRRZJgcOSdh05B042EUYXNSbVAM2EcJB4IejYuNjr64QC6SsxscNBOosC8gpbWWjAQctLZNknIKeFaoviuWoUpEbp6VcACsfFsAJ7AeAQA7mnNCaxCYpJtHRCdyr19QsBGCOLCvr6aEwkD5mV4nMDOEJzDXeMsff1g0ict0p1zYAdH-QoICNKodje3AmDA0rNgAK4Lr0d3rJgOtNtsKss2AI9OJpHphADJpE9DC4Qi4odAXtRoimpi4KIOFseviVngLkUicYMbdVLNdDAOD9UA0aW8RHIQVTEWTPKzIf1Fhx0ITgFseVDReK2YDkVLqQLVPLsWMZZMVfKJf1UGAPEVNWqVpyHD8vLq7KIDYrVpIraSoSc8FyxQr7f1kSzpHbaQJjcJTZ7vW9A9zDVD8MIAG78t2qZER6NBwEJrhWEi4tUIc7IEk%20sySLNOLV07PFgTSACOP2kZcr1dyepjPr9prr0gbdibb0dwBgPygVYgwhZZb7A5%20Q5HYbuXH9cjHg%20HXdltQXE6XZfzUk%20Scmj02MBIeB%20y6RtULrp9ME%20eAzEyPJ9z3dGmygD9PvPM783gykeha37TqoqD-oB1qbMAYAgQBx4flCW7oGKeBgbG2g7MUKE%20pYyC%20F0wBvrBZaIe0mFvFAEDnMhhFAQIpGAi2ch0We%20hMSsyDSJGLRlnIwicMgv6sVCDGoOS16CdqonAOJca1CJeRSdREx4hMvxQGATpPoC5LRvY%20GjnM6BOmW6mmmWkbCPgvZltAsy8WWvg-LMzw1jRuQpMgMAudaDE2XMEKoQxqnqXB-TvuZlkwGWyLhU6kU0fGUC2f5PrIm5WyecZ-bBWWdgOGUd74mAdh6Gk7zFTYW5FcgoRaOIEAwFVNVxmKYCNTYPYxb2JSqAxnWMlwjRqpcwjXppkzDdeRHIDiNF1cgwAtJsqreXYFgcO2tYAF79iFqiyMICAKSeZYSBA6ATbtAgXagCh6JdnqoOI7S3jRJDAGIl3lOSh32QQVh4BdOWRtAXE0U4MDCFWwCAzRIjzZe7IcVsr4Po93HDjALTkVOSlqqKLRjSsojSHYqAkNAEA-msVig9azx4NGUBRbUhLSLTqGs%20zKWeJzVOSHJ168zRAtcmzzP6CLQvWkeXw1bj97kZ0Ob8Na2H03LqEy8gsxcLIRjJW8JDDlDZbsZG0hkKMcyTTRlyfHF0v9ngLSdBAOyjkWNHYwBisI4CMj2D7ox%205MoJbORBuAh8UA-GWswQEgklEdInCcE6QTB0RwhbOxZYZ0r3G6G7Id4gAvnATyICg6AANzMMwAD0DdwAAgh0cC6hA0cQ8AqBwL45FyIgWC4H9xDkJQ8CdMI7dvXAuT2HkINwNPMDiHAa-DhvLQfCoJA-PAa-ABXUA03A6B6qIffT7Px9dxDKCyMwmMfHAACyTg6NkUAtAA0gtxAwAP3YngFup82YADVZAnj7rQRg%20I%20AAAVyLdxaHAOwcA7otAgL4beHwcHDxwPgQgpAKBUGiLwMBNMAA8L9gAEMwEQsepDJ5IJQfhTG0Q%20DIFNG9KA0QAB8dcmCl2EcwJAaBD69xgCwqguBT6T14B-Re38-4AKIEAiyICqGQOgb3OAcD2BcFKghPWihYhwBVGkCx75rF719nYxA2ZHHyhcRwAm-ALH1EcY1HxWUNKeJUBdRxojxHVykegWRMAACS2toAcCoEoz%20S8f7-xaIA4BsgdEtCgbBWB9AjE8H4DaKQZjjAWNCUwCR6AN7SKibEywCSYAAEYkkqJBmkjJWisngJyXo-JdBCmlRVINSxz1RiONsYEuA%20dlZ8AsReNxLolkePmSobx0zfGbP8akaZwTpmVMbs3AAQvVdendu7Zz7p-E%20Z9zZ5JPnfTRj88DcGfjvY%202AR7EKgKgRBDJHB4AMXAf5sBAXUPgQkNhXd0HIEwQtAhdCGHfOYRPchlDem0I%20ciphJC0UwGhWALhPDGL4UEcI0uQj65VPCbUyJ%20L5FNNaXAL5uLfmgohrIYFgyXAmN-IYcxKgrHTKmWsmZDjpmLOma46V7jHEbLFVsxVOzHH7LFZU6pESZEMviZPAATLwVlo9CAcsBdyoZxTTEaHKSoDVtLrz0rITEuJCiqAGvfsk1RnSNGZNAb03JMDzW8uKSM6IcBKlAA)

Comment: Please share fully reproducible example with expected and unexpected behavior (where you expect compiler errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to make `cssColorsObject` immutable.

```js
const cssColorsObject = {
    red: ["lightsalmon", "salmon", "darksalmon", "lightcoral", "indianred", "crimson", "firebrick", "red", "darkred"],
    orange: ["coral", "tomato", "orangered", "gold", "orange", "darkorange"],
    yellow: ['lemon']
} as const
```

Then iterate through `cssColorsObject` keys and create the desired type.

```js
type PartialCSS<T extends Record<string, ReadonlyArray<string>>> =
    Partial<{
        [Prop in keyof T]: Array<T[Prop][number]>
    }>
```

I have used have unpacked `T[Prop]` array into new similar `Array<T[Prop][number]>` because `T[Prop]` is immutable tuple where order of elements is preserved whereas new type does not require exact element order. Drawback, it allows you to use two similar elements.

Whole code:

```js
const cssColorsObject = {
    red: ["lightsalmon", "salmon", "darksalmon", "lightcoral", "indianred", "crimson", "firebrick", "red", "darkred"],
    orange: ["coral", "tomato", "orangered", "gold", "orange", "darkorange"],
    yellow: ['lemon']
} as const


type PartialCSS<T extends Record<string, ReadonlyArray<string>>> =
    Partial<{
        [Prop in keyof T]: Array<T[Prop][number]>
    }>

const result: PartialCSS<typeof cssColorsObject> = {
    red: ['salmon'],
    yellow:['salmon'] // expected error
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMEQMIgDYgE4QPICMBWApsLALwwDeAsAFAx0zoEAmAXDANoBEKAlgOYALKBACGKALbhOAGhidREqbM5MR6ANYLJYGXN6CoodGN2ceYJjxFhGTU8HQ9xEJXIBmPRjkfB1p26aqGgEAutI09DAY1nwEbFxGJspQIOIiKabRYLEBynyodspZsYFq6sUEnGER9ACeBChoAO7xAOQoBNqtITQAvjAiEHDg0DRj1FC1AA4EMAAKalBWKIgAyqsAPAAqMAQAHlAEFkMASkQYTBvQjtmyZyJM4Ci1AILoxrVXUDd8AHz-MBINToC3QSzEGyotEi9HYc3QICmMHMMHUBFqIDcMC2ITYbw%202zhCKmIXYYAAruIcAR0CFfsCYL16dQaKBILBGBBySgoGxQeCVusNpMZpi4AhkGhMLhCMRfoCKAzbG0tOBuuFoXR6o0QC12K1VWBujAAPQm3Z7GbEZi7d4YPpAA)

Comment: Wow, that's incredible. Thanks! Just spent half an hour unpacking all the elements of typescript you've used there. You're quite a few levels of abstraction above my level! Thanks again! You mentioned above to share a reproducible example. Would you like me to edit the question still?

Comment: Thanks. Reproducible example is not relevant anymore. You can edit your question , if you want, for other people. Btw, you can find more interesting examples in my blog https://catchts.com/ which is fuly dedicated to TS